# Tensorflow Dataset: Accessing row values to preprocess text data

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0, machine-translation

I have used the `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset` to read CSV data. the CSV has 2 different lang for the transformer model.

```
 train_examples = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset("./Data/training.csv", [tf.string, tf.string], header=True)
```

#printing  'train_examples'

```
<CsvDatasetV2 shapes: ((), ()), types: (tf.string, tf.string)>
```

I am trying to preprocess data for each column of text data before training the [transformer model](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/transformer). How would I pass a function like the below on the 2 columns of the data? What structure is the output from `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset`?

```
def preprocess_sentence(sentence):
   sentence = sentence.lower().strip()
   # creating a space between a word and the punctuation following it
   # eg: "he is a boy." => "he is a boy ."
   sentence = re.sub(r"([?.!,])", r" \1 ", sentence)
   sentence = re.sub(r'[" "]+', " ", sentence)
   # replacing everything with space except (a-z, A-Z, ".", "?", "!", ",")
   sentence = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z?.!,]+", " ", sentence)
   sentence = sentence.strip()
   # adding a start and an end token to the sentence
   return sentence
```

If I apply the above function, the CsvDataset object cannot handle any operations.

```
AttributeError: 'CsvDatasetV2' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 0):

> What structure is the output from tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset?

`CsvDataset` returns a tensorflow dataset which is a custom object representing an arbitrarily large dataset.

> If I apply the above function, the CsvDataset object cannot handle any operations

That's because datasets are evaluated lazily by default (with good reason, as I mentioned above they can represent huge, even infinite, datasets) so, by default, mapping operations need to be done using tensor operations.

Usefully, however, there is a tensorflow operation that allows you to call python code from tf so you *could* do something like this:

```py
pre_processed_dataset = my_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(preprocess_sentence, x, tf.string))
```

(though you should make sure `preprecess_sentence` actually takes 2 sentences as an argument in common with your dataset which is a dataset of string *pairs*).

Having said that, it would be much more optimal is if you could just translate your preprocessing function into tensor operations. Maybe something like this:

```py
def preprocess(sentence1, sentence2):
  def preprocess_sentence(sentence):
    ret = tf.strings.lower(sentence)
    ret = tf.strings.strip(ret)
    ret = tf.strings.regex_replace(ret, "([?.!,])", " \1 ")
    ret = tf.strings.regex_replace(ret, '[" "]+', " ")
    ret = tf.strings.regex_replace(ret, "[^a-zA-Z?.!,]+", " ")
    ret = tf.strings.strip(ret)
    return ret
  return preprocess_sentence(sentence1), preprocess_sentence(sentence2)
```

then you can map your dataset like this:

```py
my_preprocessed_dataset = my_dataset.map(preprocess)
```

Comment: As you have mentioned here, it would be easier if we had the flexibility to use custom python functions. Here, my `preprocess_sentence` function takes in a list of sentences and returns back a list of sentences. Now if I have to use this, there are 2 things I would have to do 1. Converting the dataset as a pair of list (lang1,lang2) (but if I use `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset` it handles this for us) 2. How do I convert the list or series to a TF object (always tensors??) (in some other function) so that it is compatible by TF processors.

Comment: On using the map function `pre_processed_dataset = my_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(preprocess_sentence, x, tf.string))
` it gives a `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: Can I also create the dataset using the following function: `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
{'inputs': preprocessed_lang1},{'outputs': preprocessed_lang2}))`

Comment: The map function does not take the single column from `CsvDataset ` - throws this error `TypeError: Expected list for 'input' argument to 'EagerPyFunc' Op, not Tensor("args_0:0", shape=(), dtype=string).`